# Can two half-cut potatoes fuse back together?

Tags: botany

If I cut a potato in half, then I hold the two parts together, will the two halves fuse back into a single potato?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could easily be answered by running a very simple experiment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, it can be answered by a small practical. Also it's off-topic.

Comment: I do not agree. While the experiment can be done easily, it does not explain the underlying process. Will it hold together because it is glued by the starch, or do the cells regrow, or is there something that make it really impossible? As a novice in biology, I really thing this deserves a detailed answer.

Comment: A question does not become off topic simply because it can be easily answered using a simple experiment. It looks on topic (may be a bit funny but still related to biology) and can have a scientific answer.